# Does Windows Server Backup include GPOs?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

All of the documentation I can find on backing up Group Policy discusses using the Group Policy Management Editor to back up the GPOs separately from the rest of the domain.  Any scheduled or automated backup procedure relies on a custom PowerShell script.  Are GPOs backed up via Windows Server Backup like the rest of the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're backing up a Domain Controller and you're performing a Full/Bare Metal Recovery backup then Group Policy will be backed up as part of the backup.

Comment: See also [System State](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938537.aspx) backup.

Comment: Right, a Full or Bare Metal Recovery backup would include the System State, which would include Group Policy. A System State backup on it's own would also backup Group Policy (SYSVOL) and the Active Directory database.

Comment: Thank you.  I read that documentation and it didn't indicate GPO but I guess I didn't realize GPO was in the SYSVOL.